# Why am i getting an error near the if statement here?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
for i in {1..10}
if [ $i=5 ]
then
    echo "Youve completed 5 iterations, do you wish to continue?"
    read input
    if [$input ="Yes"]
    then
        continue
else
        break

fi

  if [$i==10]
  then
        break

do     
 echo "Iteration no: $i"
 echo "Enter a number"
 read number
 echo "youve entered $number"
done
```

Comment: please update the question to include the complete error message; there are actually several syntax issues ... `for` loop is missing the initial `do`; a couple `if` statements are missing ending `fi`s; your `do ... done` block doesn't appear to match up with any leading `while` or `for` ...

Comment: [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will give you good suggestions

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful to review the basics of Bash Scripting a bit more before jumping into the fire.

```bash
if [ "foo" = "foo" ]
then
    echo "Equal"
else
    echo "Not Equal"
fi
```

In Bash script, the spacing between variables and brackets is significant, meaning the if statement above is NOT the same as `[ "foo"=="foo"]` (Notice the lack of a space)

Now let's add a loop

```bash
for i in {1..10}
do
    if [ $i -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo "Equal"
    else
        echo "Not Equal"
    fi
done
```

If you're comparing integers, you should use `-eq` for an equals comparison.

Make sure you're adding the 'do' and 'done' statements. It helps to use indents in your code to make it easier to follow the script execution. Everything 4 spaces over will execute inside the loop.

From here you should be able to build up to your final script which checks for user input.

It's fun to jump in and try new things but always be sure to reference the documentation! https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Commands

Comment: It should be `[ "$a" = "$b" ]`, not `[ "$a" == "$b" ]`.

Comment: See the relevant POSIX spec at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html (`[` being a synonym for `test`). Yes, `==` is always supported in bash's builtin version of `[`, but being in the habit of using it means that code will break with baseline POSIX `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point, I'll edit

Comment: BTW, in bash (which is needed for `{1..10}`, you can use `(( i == 1 ))` instead of `[ "$i" -eq 1]` (note the quotes, without which error messages when `i` is empty are less useful and weird values of IFS can cause surprising behavior; it's unusual to have something like `IFS=0`, but there's been a time I was parsing a file format where it was appropriate to do so)..